# Nginx ingress returns 404 error for a txt file in the domain

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

My development team has requested me to deny access to all yml and txt files inside the pod. But they wanted an exception for a single txt file, say helloworld.txt

so what I did is, added the following deny rules in the ingress resource:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  location ~* /helloworld.txt {
              allow all;
              }
  location ~* ^.+\.(yml|yaml|txt)$ {
                  deny all;
                  return 403;
              }
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nginx-proxy
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
```

But **domain.com/helloworld.txt** returns a 404 not found.

Without the above two location blocks/rules, **domain.com/helloworld.txt** loads just fine.

What am I missing?.

Comment: Have you specified your `host` correctly? if yes, try to change your location modifier to `location ~* "^/helloworld.txt { ...`

Comment: Yes, I edited the question and added spec,host part as well. The solution `location ~* "^/helloworld.txt` did not work unfortunately.

Comment: sorry, I've meant to have whole path into the brackets, so it will be: `location ~* "^/helloworld.txt" {
              allow all;
              }`